# Decompiling/Unpacking a File (Reverse Engineering the Compiler)

Tags: visual-foxpro, decompiling, foxpro, decompiler, unpack

I'm using a program that can pack/compile a folder with files into a single ***.xyz** file that only that program can decompile and read. In order for the program to create a compiled file the flag:

```
[Compile]
Decompile=1
```

must be in the file **Meta.ini**. If not, the file cannot be unpacked/decompiled and there is no way to get back the source files.

I have created a compiled file and have lost the source files. I forgot to add the decompile flag, so I currently have no way to unpack the file and continue my work. I can still compile and decompile files using the program as long as I include the flag. The file produced is in the FoxPro FPT format. The program is written in Visual Basic.

**To Summarise:**

- I have a compiled/packed file that I need to decompile/unpack.
- I have access to the program that can compile and decompile the file.
- I don't have the required decompile flag in the file.
- The file produced is in the FoxPro FPT format.
- The program is written in Visual Basic.

I know where the flag needs to go but I have no way of inserting it without first decompiling/unpacking the file (that I know of). My options are either to find a way of decompiling the file itself, or find a way to isolate the decompiler from the rest of the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could set a breakpoint at the point where the (un)packer reads and evaluates the setting for 'Decompile', change the result and let it continue. Barring that we'd need a sample of an packed ('compiled') file; e.g. if its XOR-shrouded then you can punch new values through the shroud without removing it first, e.g. XOR with (old_value XOR new_value) in the right place. Works for removing the so-called decompilation protection from Refox-branded files, for example (which only Refox honours anyway).

Comment: @DarthGizka How would I do that? Would I open the program in a debugger and capture what it does when it decompiles a .xyz file? I can create a dummy file with the flag that I can then decompile.

Comment: Well, debugging and spelunking is discussed over at [Reverse Engineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/). Basically, you take a debugger like IDA or Cheat Engine and set a hardware read breakpoint on the constant string "Decompile" in the data segment, see what develops and follow your nose. Putting up two small examples -  identical except for the Decompile setting - in a place like PasteBin would allow folks to evaluate the situation but normally we'd like to get our mitts on the program (dunno what your licence situation is there). The DBF and FPT structures a fairly well

Comment: are fairly well documented, it's the rest that's tricky. I know the FXP/APP structure in and out - including the XOR shrouding that you get with the `ENCRYPT` keyword when compiling - and all the snake oil behind Refox and Xitech Cryptor. If there's none of the Foxish stuff then the folks over at Reverse Engineering would be better able to help.

Comment: @DarthGizka I'm just getting to grips with Cheat Engine. I've found the hex code that calls: `.get_DecompileToolStripMenuItem`. Would I insert this somehow when the program loads the context menu that shows the Decompile option?

Comment: That's probably somewhere in the remote environs of interesting stuff; there must be better, closer hits on "Decompile". However, stuff like that is the bailiwick of [Reverse Engineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/); the folks over there should be able to help you.

Comment: @DarthGizka I'll make a thread over there, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @DarthGizka [here](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11483/decompiling-unpacking-a-compiled-packed-file-or-somehow-inserting-a-flag) it is if you want to see how things go.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying

> I have access to the program that can compile and decompile the file.

Then simply modify the portion that checks that flag and decompile.

Comment: would the best way to do that be with a memory editor like Cheat Engine? I've made a thread over at Reverse Engineering which seems like the best place for this problem.

Comment: No, you don't need cheat engine or anything like that. You said you have access to the program. Recode it not to check for the metadata and compile and run.

Comment: I meant I have access to the executable file, not the source code. Apart from memory editing is there any way I can get the program to either get a positive when checking for the flag or to decompile without checking for the flag at all?